# Return a ranking from tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here my table structure:

**___Rooms:**

```
|--------|------------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_Name   |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | Room 1     |
| 2      | Room 2     |
| 3      | Room 3     |
|--------|------------|
```

**___Bookings:**

```
|--------|------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_RoomId |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 1          |
| 2      | 2          |
| 3      | 2          |
|--------|------------|
```

**___BillableDatas:**

```
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Item   |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
| 1      | 1             | 2017-02-21 | Night      |
| 2      | 1             | 2017-02-22 | Night      |
| 3      | 1             | 2017-02-23 | Night      |
| 4      | 1             | 2017-02-24 | Night      |
| 5      | 2             | 2017-02-30 | Night      |
| 6      | 2             | 2017-02-31 | Night      |
| 7      | 1             | 2017-02-31 | Night      |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|
```

I would like to know the most popular room.

The desired result should be:

```
|------------|------------|------------|
| ROO_Name   | Night Nb   | Percentage |
|------------|------------|------------|
| Room 1     | 5          | 71.42      |
| Room 2     | 2          | 28.57      |
| Room 3     | 0          | 0          |
|------------|------------|------------|
```

What I already tried:

```
SELECT r.ROO_Id
     , Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) NumBookings
     , Concat(
         Format(
           Sum(CASE WHEN BOO_Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
           / TotalBookings 
           * 100
         , 0) ) AS PercentageTotal
  FROM (  ___Rooms r LEFT JOIN ___Bookings b ON r.ROO_Id = b.BOO_RoomId
       ) INNER JOIN (SELECT BOO_HotelId
                          , Count(*) AS TotalBookings
                       FROM ___Bookings 
                      GROUP BY BOO_HotelId
                    ) AS TotalHotelBookings 
                 ON r.ROO_HotelId = TotalHotelBookings.BOO_HotelId
 WHERE r.ROO_HotelId = :hotel_id
 GROUP BY r.ROO_Id
 ORDER BY NumBookings DESC
```

But it doesn't work actually.

Could anyone help me with this please ?

You could use the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe0a77

Comment: @McNets: the tables are updated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/390b1.

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the 'impossible dates' and I've set a [rextester](http://rextester.com/COSZO89518) sample.

First group by RoomId and BookingId and calculate percentage.

```
(
 SELECT      b.BOO_RoomId, bd.BIL_BookingId, 
             COUNT(*) as NumNights,
             COUNT(*) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ___BillableDatas) AS Percent 
 FROM        ___BillableDatas bd
 LEFT JOIN   ___Bookings B
 ON          b.BOO_Id = bd.BIL_BookingId
 GROUP BY    b.BOO_RoomId, bd.BIL_BookingId
) co
```

Then LEFT JOIN with rooms table and show all values:

```
SELECT      r.ROO_Name,
            COALESCE(NumNights, 0) NumNights,
            COALESCE(Percent, 0) Percent
FROM        ___Rooms r
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT      b.BOO_RoomId, bd.BIL_BookingId, 
                        COUNT(*) as NumNights,
                        COUNT(*) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                          FROM ___BillableDatas
                                          WHERE BIL_Date >= '2017-02-01' AND BIL_Date < '2017-02-23'
                                          ) AS Percent 
            FROM        ___BillableDatas bd
            LEFT JOIN   ___Bookings B
            ON          b.BOO_Id = bd.BIL_BookingId
            WHERE       BIL_Date >= '2017-02-01' AND BIL_Date < '2017-02-23'
            GROUP BY    b.BOO_RoomId, bd.BIL_BookingId
            ) co
ON          R.ROO_Id = co.BOO_RoomId
;

+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| ROO_Name | BIL_BookingId | NumNights | Percent |
+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| Room 1   |       1       |     5     | 71,4286 |
| Room 2   |       2       |     2     | 28,5714 |
| Room 3   |       0       |     0     |  0,0000 |
+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Oh look perfect. last thing, how can I run this query but only for a dates range please?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I can't accept your solution like on StackOverflow ?

Comment: You should be able to accept it.

Comment: Strange, I can't see it... :(

Comment: @F__M maybe tomorrow ;)

Comment: @F__M or perhaps because you haven't registered your account yet. Please do (register / login with you SO account) and I think then you'll be able to accept. It seems you have asked the question while you were not loggen in. You may have to merge the 2 accounts. Check this: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @McNets: i foud a problem with the solution when I specify the date `BIL_Date >= '2017-02-01' AND BIL_Date < '2017-02-23'`, I have 20% whereas, because I do not have any other bookings I should have 100% no ? See the problem in action: http://rextester.com/COSZO89518

Comment: Yes, I've edited the answer, you should filter overal  total too.

Comment: @McNets: the percent is still in error: http://rextester.com/YWDJ10847

Comment: Remove bd. prefix http://rextester.com/MMVMI20081